# MATLAB Grayscale showing RGB output

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rgb, grayscale

I'm using these lines of code to convert an RGB image to grayscale.

```
% ===========================
% GRAYSCALE IMAGE
% ===========================
% --- Executes on button press in btnGrayscale.
function btnGrayscale_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global origImage;    
imageGray = rgb2gray(origImage);
axes(handles.axesEdited);
image(imageGray);
```

The output doesn't show a grayscale image though.

[image]

What seems to be the problem? I'm running MATLAB 6.5 on Windows 7, by the way.

Comment: You might need to do `imshow(imageGray,[])` to see the result

Comment: Add `colormap gray` after the call to `image` because it's not the default colormap (its either `jet` or `parula` depending on your Matlab version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
imshow(imageGray,[])
```

From **[imshow](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html):**

`imshow(I,[]) displays the grayscale image I, where [] is an empty matrix that specifies that you want imshow to scale the image based on the range of pixel values in I, using [min(I(:)) max(I(:))] as the display range.`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answers! I thought the problem's with my graphics driver (lol), but when I've tried showing the output on a figure (not on the axis), I found the problem.

Here's a simple solution I've found.

Instead of using `image(imageGray);`, I've used `imshow(imageGray);`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way can call one band to show the gray image

`imshow(rgb(:,:,2));`